# How can I see contracts and events in the ganache UI when deploying vyper contracts locally with brownie?

Tags: ganache, brownie

Im trying to run: brownie run scripts/deploy_script.py --network development

I have these 2 config files:

```
# truffle-config.js
module.exports = {
    networks: {
      development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: "*"
      }
    },
    contracts_directory: '/repos/blockchain/contracts',
    contracts_build_directory: '/repos/blockchain/build/contracts',
  };

# Brownie config
networks:
    default: development
    development:
      cmd_settings:
        port: 8545

dev_deployment_artifacts: true
```

Comment: could you please add more details since your issue is mostly code so it is hard for people to follow along.

Comment: Basically my problem is that I want to take full advantage of the Ganache UI. It has a tab that says Events and one that says Contracts. However when Im developing with vyper on brownie they dont show up when I compile them and deploy them. I just want to be able to see them in the UI like you would expect.